# Buscar nombre en una string con python

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy intentando buscar un nombre en una string que cambia el contenido. El valor que busco es, por ejemplo, `Elon Musk` en la siguiente string:

```
line = ISISST123 ISIRTONSA ISIPLK01200 ISISNSElon Musk ISIGTO192
```

Como digo, los valores de la string pueden cambiar.

Mi código y output es el siguiente:

```
# nombre
nombre= re.search(r"SNS(\w+)", line)
nombreReal= ''.join(nombre.group(1))
print (nombreReal)

>> Elon
```

¿Como debería hacer para que imprima el nombre completo?

Comment: Después del nombre, ¿qué viene? ¿Será siempre algo que empiece con "ISI"? ¿El nombre tendrá siempre 2 partes, o puden ser 3 ó 1?

Comment: Si, después del nombre siempre se encuentra la string `ISI`. El nombre puede tener 1, 2 o mas partes, depende de la string que se use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La expresión regular debe reconocer un secuencia de letras mayúsculas/minúsculas y espacios. Este patrón es "[A-Za-z ]+". No usamos "\w", ya que este también reconoce dígitos, que no forman parte de un nombre.

Para acotar el patrón, el OP nos dice que antes viene "SNS" y después siempre viene "ISI". El patrón queda así: "SNS([A-Za-z ]+)ISI". Agregamos los paréntesis para *capturar* el texto reconocido.

Con eso podemos escribir:

```
def get_name(line):
    nombre= re.search(r"SNS([a-zA-Z ]+)ISI", line)
    return ''.join(nombre.group(1))
```

**Demo**

```
tests = [
    "ISISST123 ISIRTONSA ISIPLK01200 ISISNSElon Musk ISIGTO192",
    "ISISST123 ISIRTONSA ISIPLK01200 ISISNSElon Travis Musk ISIGTO192",
    "ISISST123 ISIRTONSA ISIPLK01200 ISISNSElon ISIGTO192"
]

for test in tests:
    print(get_name(test))
```

produce

```
Elon Musk 
Elon Travis Musk 
Elon
```

Comment: He implementado el código para realizar la búsqueda sin utilizar el método, y me sale el siguiente error al ejectura el codigo: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: @andyio. Habría que ver el código completo, ver qué contiene `line`....